# Best way for multiple devs to Share development MSQL database remotely

Tags: mysql, wordpress, workflow, remote-access, remote-server

I work remotely and the company I work with has just added a new junior dev. Since it is not just me anymore, I had to start thinking about our workflow, and how best to get it set up. We pretty much are exclusively using WordPress.

The company has a dev server, but because they are half way around the world, I get a 200ms ping which really slows me down, my normal workflow for new sites has been running a local dev environment and then updating the theme and syncing the database to their development server. Once everyone is happy with dev - we migrate it to production.

With our new junior dev - and the possibility of bringing more devs on board, I am trying to figure out the best way of managing/syncing the database. It is easy for me - by myself - to update the database, but when you have multiple people who need to access and change it, how do you do it?
I have tried using a ssh tunnel and accessing mysql on the dev server. It works, but I was getting 15-20 second page loads.
I had a look at https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db, but that does not handle multiple versions of the db.

The company that wrote that also offers a service - https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro - and whilst they have a package that supports multiple devs for the low cost of $599 for the first year - it does not appear to solve the issue with having multiple versions of the db out there.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to do this with WP/MySQL?

Comment: shared source control. Then each dev can check out a copy of the latest DB with latest changes, and run it locally. Then update each other with your respective changes, and decide when to promote to your dev/test/etc environments. Of course you may run into conflicts, and usually the task of resolving them is given to a more senior or experienced developer.